# APIController FromBody arg is null on put requests sometimes, but raw request has a valid body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller that looks similar to the following:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody]List<MyObject> fromBody)
{
    if (fromBody == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(fromBody)} must not be null");

    // Unimportant junk
}
```

Very rarely, the InvalidOperationException is thrown during a request.  But the raw request data has the correct content and headers(I use raygun for exception reporting and it captures the raw request and the json content is there and valid).  Are there any reasons that this could occur?

The headers are the same between both a successful request and a bad one, and are as follows(With my website and any Azure id's redacted):

```
Connection: "Keep-Alive"
Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
Accept: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
Accept-Encoding: "gzip"
Host: "redacted"
Max-Forwards: "10"
User-Agent: "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/M4B30Z)"
Content-Length: "55392"
X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL: "redacted"
X-Original-URL: "redacted"
X-ARR-LOG-ID: "redacted"
DISGUISED-HOST: "redacted"
X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID: "redacted"
WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME: "redacted"
X-Forwarded-For: "redacted"
X-ARR-SSL: "redacted"
X-Forwarded-Proto: "https"
MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN: "redacted"
X-Original-For: "redacted"
X-Original-Proto: "http"
```

Unfortunately I cannot disclose the actual body of the message due to policies beyond my control, but it is composed of a 100% valid json array of objects totaling in the correct length in regard to the Content-Length.  And when my client does a retry with the same content/headers, it succeeds.

My suspicion is that it is potentially timed out requests still entering the controller, and then being unable to read the request body due to the timeout.  Clients are android devices so they go in and out of internet connectivity constantly.  But I don't know why it would enter the controller at all in that case.

Comment: Is the `Content-Type` header to set `application/json` in the exceptional cases?

Comment: Yes, the request has the correct Content-Type

Comment: Please add a good request and a bad request to the question, with headers.

Comment: where's the body?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to disclose the contents of the body itself.  I can assure you it is 100% valid, I was able to re-run the put request as reported and it succeeds, leading me to believe there is some issue outside of the request itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Asp.NET core had a bug that resulted in this behavior.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7551

It has been patched in 2.1.X+ of which a preview release is available.